# angular function to change json based on selection from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular noob here.

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8g8Ya5LaGOItJPaZPw6?p=preview) where there is a list. One item in the list has a flag symbol which opens a modal when clicked. The flag is applied to only one item in the list for which `primary_program` is set to **true**.

This is the format of my json file:

```
{
        "student": 2773951, 
        "credits_completed": 26, 
        "academic_program_gpa": null, 
        "primary_program": true, 
        "academic_program": {
            "id": 596, 
            "acad_program_category": 2, 
            "acad_program_type": 2, 
            "program_title": "Associate in Sciences Degree", 
            "required_credits": 60, 
            "min_gpa": 2.0, 
            "description": "", 
            "colleges": [
                200, 
                300, 
                400, 
                500, 
                600, 
                700, 
                800
            ]
        }
    }
```

In the modal, i have the same list as a dropdown. When one program is selected, i want the app to change the value of `primary_program` to **true** for the selected to true and the rest of the list to **false**. How do i write a function to achieve this functionality? I tried using an `ng-change()` function. But it does not make any change to the json. How can i approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
<select ng-change="onChange()">
```